# AudioSystem be accessed from Java EE web app?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, audio-streaming, javasound

Can you access a clients audio input and output using the AudioSystem class through a Java EE application? If not, how would you go about doing it?

Comment: If it's webapp, the client access it via browser. So you want to play an audio file or something more complex?

Comment: I would like to get access to the microphone on the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the new  `navigator.getUserMedia()` and **HTML5 APIs**.

Here some examples:

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/09/Live-Web-Audio-Input-Enabled

http://html5-examples.craic.com/microphone_input_with_spectrogram.html

---

**ADDED**

It's also possible to use an **java applet** to control the microphone and audio, but applets are old and too much intrusive.

Most websites that use this kind of feature use a flash object:

http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html